For a modern Turboprop/Jet will going at 300/400 mph TAS at 10000 feet require more thrust/use more fuel per unit time vs going 600mph at 30,000 feet?
My understanding is one of the primary reasons why modern planes Cruise at around 30,000 to 40,000 ft is because of the lower air density less results in less drag. So for a given thrust, an airplane can fly faster in the higher altitude ...
However, how does fuel efficiency figure in ? To generate the given thrust does the plane require less fuel? Use a simplified toy example (Scenario A) to At 300 mph True Air speed. At 10,000 ft. Versus flying at 600 mph at 30,000 ft. Will flying 600 mph at 30,000 ft require both less thrust and use less fuel per unit time versus 300 mph at 10,000 ft, ?
Or (Scenario B): Are talking about requiring less thrust and less fuel per unit time for equivalent  Air Speeds at different altitudes? That is, is flying at  300 mph at 30,000 ft requires less thrust and consumes less fuel per unit time than 300 mph at 10000 ft (assuming 300 mph is sufficient  speed to generate lift at that altitude of 30000 ft of lower air density). Let us ignore like jet engine efficiency for now at given altitude, And just focus on drag drag, thrust and fuel consumption...I know modern engines are also optimized to work at certain altitude window etc
Actually it occurred to me I may have got it all kind of backwards. The Same amount of thrust at a higher altitude translates to greater True air speed- due to lower drag due to lower air density at higher altitudes. This means you cover more distance for same amount of fuel! It is fuel per unit distance (miles per gallon) that is reduced, not fuel consumption per se (Liters per unit of Thrust). Is this on the correct track?  
it Scenario A while going 600 mph at 30000 feet at constant thrust may use similar fuel per unit TIME vs 300 mph at 10000 feet, it will likely use less fuel per unit DISTANCE traveling greater distance per GALLON not necessarily per unit TIME. As for Scenario B: Obviously going 300 mph at 30000 feet (assuming 300 mph is sufficient to generate enough lift at 30000 feet with lower air density) will use less fuel per unit time and require less thrust than going 300 mph at 10000 ft (due to lower drag due to lower air density at higher altitudes) Is this understanding correct track?

Actually it occurred to me I may have got it all kind of backwards. The Same amount of thrust at a higher altitude translates to greater True air speed- due to lower drag due to lower air density at higher altitudes. This means you cover more distance for same amount of fuel! It is fuel per unit distance (miles per gallon) that is reduced, not fuel consumption per se (Liters per unit of Thrust). Is this towards the correct track to answering my question?

You can just delete the bold-text part. There's no need to add every version and edit or change in your post.

There are a lot of competing effects that depend on a lot of details.  This makes it very difficult to give a short (correct) answer.
Instead, I'll present a set of figures from some calculations I've done on an aircraft meant to be similar to a typical large transport aircraft in service today.

The chart of most interest to you will be the 3rd on the bottom row.  The aircraft's Specific Range (SR) is the fuel economy in terms of distance covered -- the units here are nautical mile per 1000 pounds of fuel.
As you can see, this aircraft's best range is at 36,000 ft and about Mach 0.85 -- where it gets about 16 nmi/1000lb.
The bold line in each chart represents the zero specific excess power line.  That is the boundary of the flight envelope -- the aircraft can not fly in steady level flight outside this boundary.
Also of interest is the 2nd chart on the bottom row.  The aircraft's fuel flow (wdot_f) is the fuel consumption in terms of time aloft -- the units here are pounds per hour.
As you can see, this aircraft's best fuel flow is between 20,000 and 30,000 lbm/hr.  The chart doesn't have enough contours to really pick out a precise optimum value.  However, we can see that you can achieve better than 30,000 lbm/hr from sea level until 40,000 ft -- so long as you carefully choose the correct airspeed for each altitude.
The figures on this chart are:

Lift to drag ratio (L/D) which is dimensionless


Used to optimize glide distance.


Power off rate of descent (RoD) in ft/s


Used to optimize glide time.


Specific excess power (P_s) or rate of climb in ft/min


Used to optimize climb time.


Climb angle in degrees


Used to optimize climb distance (obstacle avoidance).


Fuel specific climb (f_s) in ft/lbm


Used to optimize climb fuel consumption


Fuel consumption (wdot_f) in lbm/hr


Used to optimize flight endurance


Specific range (SR) in nmi/1000lbm


Used to optimize flight range


True airspeed (V_t) in kts


Used to help convert these charts from Mach to kts true.

Calculating these charts requires a drag model of the aircraft that includes effects of compressibility.  It also requires an engine thrust and fuel flow model that includes the effects of speed, altitude, and throttle setting.  It also requires a standard atmosphere model that includes the variation of pressure, density, and temperature with altitude.
Some information about the aircraft is also required.  Most importantly, the wing loading and thrust to weight ratio.  Some other minor assumptions are required.  For example, in this case, a gross weight at the middle of cruise (about half the onboard fuel has been burned) is assumed.
At every point in the flight envelope, the drag is calculated.  Then, the appropriate throttle setting for each chart is determined -- for the gliding metrics, zero throttle -- for the climbing metrics, full throttle -- for the equilibrium metrics, throttle that gives thrust equal to drag.  Once the throttle setting is known, the TSFC can be determined and the rest of the computations can proceed.
